# Golang avoiding code duplication

Tags: go, code-duplication

I have two structs at the moment.

```
type One struct {
    Name  string
    Age   int
    ID    int
    Owner string
}

type Two struct {
    ID    int
    Make  string
    Bags  string
    Age   int
    Owner string
}
```

These structs map to a table in a DB, I use an interface to provide access to the DB and contents. In this case just a listing of the data in One and Two based on the owner.

```
type dbInterface interface {
    ListOnesByOwner(owner string) ([]*One, error)
    LitsTwosByOwner(owner string) ([]*Two, error)
}
```

The listing functions are the same except for the structs.

```
func (db *DB) ListOnes(owner string) ([]*One, error) {
    ones = make([]*One, 0)
    q := db.NewQuery("One").
        Filter("Owner =", owner).
        Order("Name")

    keys, err := db.client.GetAll(q, &ones)
    for i, k := range keys {
        ones[i].ID = k.ID
    }
    return ones, nil
}

func (db *DB) ListTwos(owner string) ([]*Two, error) {
    twos = make([]*Two, 0)
    q := db.NewQuery("Two").
        Filter("Owner =", owner).
        Order("Name")

    keys, err := db.client.GetAll(q, &twos)
    for i, k := range keys {
        twos[i].ID = k.ID
    }
    return twos, nil
}

func main() {
    ones, err := DB.ListOnesByOwner(user.ID)
    twos, err := DB.ListTwosByOwner(user.ID)
}
```

I'm fairly new to GO, so I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to reduce the code duplication seen here? If I was to add a couple more structs then it would be unwieldy because the amount of code duplication needed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Before I post my answer, I have a question. Is the second argument to`db.client.GetAll` an `inteface{}`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PaulHankin he's not asking for a general code review, he's asking a specific question about how to use the Go language. Seems legit to me for SO.

Comment: Could you please share what package you're using that implements the `db.client.GetAll` method/func? From the looks of it, you might not need to loop over the keys at all since you're already passing a pointer to the "destination" value... therefore I'm assuming `GetAll` fills out its second argument for you and the returned keys are just for consideration and do not have to be used necessarily... For example `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore`'s very similar `*Query.GetAll` method works that way.

Comment: @mkopriva I'm using the datastore package

Comment: While the accepted answers definitely answer your question, I would suggest that you organize your code into packages and not worry so much about the code duplication. My reasoning being that it's much easier to work with the data if loaded into a struct.  You don't have to write conversions (using reflect, which would lead to a performance drop), accessing and modifying the data will be easier, and lastly because you've created a well defined struct you will know exactly what's in the object you're querying for, which means no guessing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `db.client.GetAll` takes an `interface{}` as its second argument, which it appears to, you can in fact DRY it out:

```
func (db *DB) dryGet(owner, table string, result interface{}) error {
    q := db.NewQuery(table).Filter("Owner =", owner).Order("Name")
    keys,err := db.client.GetAll(q, &result)
    return err
}
```

Converting the result to a map is a little more difficult because Go lacks generics, and your structs have no methods that could be used to interface them. It's possible but would require, at the least, creating a `getID` method on each type, creating a `hasID` interface, and then returning a `map[int]hasID`, which the caller would then have to cast the values of back to the struct type to access any other fields. Not optimal, but doable. However, the above solution would at least let you eliminate a good portion of duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the accepted answer, if you're using [google.golang.org/appengine/datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference) you don't need to loop over the keys, unless you want to.

From the [GetAll docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Query.GetAll): (emphasis mine)

> GetAll runs the query in the given context and returns all keys that
>   match that query, **as well as appending the values to dst**.

So you could simplify your two methods to something like this:

```
func (db *DB) ListOnes(owner string) ([]*One, error) {
    ones = make([]*One, 0)
    q := db.NewQuery("One").
        Filter("Owner =", owner).
        Order("Name")

    if _, err := db.client.GetAll(q, &ones); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return ones, nil
}

func (db *DB) ListTwos(owner string) ([]*Two, error) {
    twos = make([]*Two, 0)
    q := db.NewQuery("Two").
        Filter("Owner =", owner).
        Order("Name")

    if _, err := db.client.GetAll(q, &twos); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return twos, nil
}
```

This is still quite a lot of duplication, so you could now generalize your code with an approach like in the accepted answer, e.g.:

```
type dbInterface interface {
    ListByType(owner, typ string, dst interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error)
}

func (db *DB) ListByType(owner, typ string, dst interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error) {
    q := db.NewQuery(typ).
        Filter("Owner =", owner).
        Order("Name")

    return db.client.GetAll(q, dst)
}
```

And you can use that implementation like this:

```
func main() {
    // ignore keys if you don't need them
    ones := []*One{}
    if _, err := DB.ListByType(user.ID, "One", &ones); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // use keys if you need them
    twos := []*Two{}
    keys, err := DB.ListByType(user.ID, "Two", &twos)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

And by the way, if you want to control how your types, `One` and `Two` etc., are loaded from the datastore, you could have them implement the [PropertyLoadSaver](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#PropertyLoadSaver) interface.